# Tor can't access its dir?

Tags: onion-services

I've tried to set up a tor hidden service on `/var/hidden`.

And after chmod-ing it to *777* and chown-ing it to *debian-tor* it still won't work. Why is that? Why doesn't it have permission to write to that directory and it has to write the default `/var/lib/tor`?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the logfile? If yes, please post them here.

Comment: Also, the configuration for your hidden service from torrc might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu, then the apparmor policy will prevent writes anywhere but in `/var/lib/tor`.

I made a `/var/lib/tor/hidden-services` on my machines; that might work for you too.

You could also modify the apparmor policy, or disable apparmor.

PS: 777 is probably a bad idea.